Prove $|M/G|=\sum_{x \in M} {\frac{1}{|G(x)|}}$
Let $G$ be a finite group operating on a finite set $M$. $|M/G|$ is the number of orbits. I want to prove that
$|M/G|=\sum_{x \in M} {\frac{1}{|G(x)|}}$
This question is in preparation of Burnside-Lemma and sadly I don't know how to approach it. I got the tip to determine the number of elements in $\{ (\sigma, x) \in G \times M \space | \space \sigma x=x\}$ but don't know how that helps me

Are you sure you wrote the equality correctly?

First, you can decompose $M$ into orbits, both members splits accordingly. Then you’re left to prove the case where the action is transitive, that is, $$1=\sum_{x\in M}\frac 1M.$$

I think the tip is really useful for the follow-up.

For every orbit, say $H = G(x)$,
$$
 \sum_{y \in G(x)} \frac{1}{|G(y)|} = \sum_{y \in G(x)} \frac{1}{|G(x)|} = 1
$$
The sum in the question is
$$
\sum_{H\ is \ an \ orbit} \sum_{x \in H} \frac{1}{|G(x)|} = \sum_{H\ is \ an \ orbit} 1 = |M/G|.
$$
